How to flash TWRP on a Samsung device via cmd?
My phone is Samsung Galaxy A12 (sm-A125F) on Android 12. When I want to flash the twrp.img file, I get this error in cmd
C:\Users\KAPI\Downloads\platform-tools>fastboot boot TWRP.img
FAILED to upload file 'boot.img' (26974 KB) (remote: 'unknown command')
fastboot: error: Command failed`

How to flash TWRP on a Samsung device via cmd?

The remote: unknown command part should refer to the boot command seems to be not implemented on your device. Samsung devices usually have a limited fastboot as flashing is primarily done via Odin/Heimdall.
